Failling to run a waitress (flask) webserver with NGINX
I have been trying to run a flask waitress server on ubuntu with NGINX.
This is my current NGINX config:
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;

    client_max_body_size 64M;  # Adjust the size as needed
    large_client_header_buffers 4 32k;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:80;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

And my waitress application below:
    def start(self):
        # Start the database instance
        self.db.start()
        # Set the DEBUG flag to False in production mode
        self.application.app.config["DEBUG"] = False
        # Store a reference to the application instance
        app_instance = self.application.app
        # If we are in production mode
        if self.prod:
            # Set the host to "0.0.0.0" (all network interfaces) and the port to 8080
            url = "127.0.0.1:80"
            # Print the URL that the application is running on
            print(f"Running PROD: http://{url}")
            # Start the application with Waitress, a production-ready WSGI server
            # The number of threads is set to 40
            self.register()
            waitress.serve(app_instance, listen=url, threads=10)
        else:
            # If we are in development mode
            print("Running DEV")
            # Run the application with its built-in development server
            # The host is set to "0.0.0.0" (all network interfaces), the port is 8080,
            # and debug mode is enabled
            self.register()
            self.application.run(host="127.0.0.1", port=80, debug=True,url_scheme='https', threaded=True)

What I am having trouble with, the webpage previously returned error 400 header size issues hence I specified a large_client_header_buffers object, and now it seems to return error 500 continuously.
And the most recent logs from nginx are as follows:
2024/06/21 20:15:03 [alert] 2935#2935: *48088 socket() failed (24: Too many open files) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: mydomain.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.0", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:80/", host: "mydomain.com"

I have got the flask app setup to run on crontab when the system boots, and NGINX also starts on boot.
Any help at all would be appreciated!
